# database error android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

i am getting this error:                                .SQLiteException: no such table: Entry_table (code 1): , while compiling:

```
INSERT INTO Entry_table(AMOUNT,CARET,BALANCE,AMOUNT_PAID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

my code:

```
public class Entry extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnsbmt1;
    Spinner spiner2;
    EditText milkcaret,amount, amountp,bal;


    DatabaseHelper mydb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);
        mydb=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        btnsbmt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit2);
        spiner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        milkcaret=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1_de);
        amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2_de);
        amountp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt3_de);
        bal=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_de);


        adddata2();

    }

    public void adddata2(){
        btnsbmt1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean inserted = mydb.insertdatat(milkcaret.getText().toString(),amount.getText().toString(),amountp.getText().toString(),bal.getText().toString());

                        if (inserted)
                            Toast.makeText(Entry.this, "data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Entry.this, "database error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

*/

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Sales.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME1="Insert_table";
public static final String TABLE_NAME2="Entry_table";




public static final String COL_ID="ID";
public static final String Col_NAME="NAME";



public static final String Col_CARET="CARET";
public static final String Col_AMOUNT="AMOUNT";
public static final String Col_AMOUNT_PAID="AMOUNT_PAID";
public static final String Col_BALANCE="BALANCE";




public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);


}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME1 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CARET INTEGER, AMOUNT INTEGER,AMOUNT_PAID INTEGER,BALANCE INTEGER)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME1);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME2);
    onCreate(db);

}
public boolean insertdata(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Col_NAME, name);
    long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME1,null,contentValues);
    if(result== -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


public boolean insertdatat(String caret,String amount,String amount_paid,String balance ){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(Col_CARET,caret);
    contentValues.put(Col_AMOUNT,amount);
    contentValues.put(Col_AMOUNT_PAID,amount_paid);
    contentValues.put(Col_BALANCE,balance);

    long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME2,null,contentValues);
    if(result== -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


}
```

Comment: Please post your `DatabaseOpenHelper`.

Comment: you are trying to insert into a table that is not exist

Comment: getting error in adddata 2

Comment: Your delete statements are missing a space: `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME2);` should be `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME2);`

Comment: db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME1);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME2); i am only getting problem in Table 2

Comment: its not working! i inserted the space db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  "+TABLE_NAME2);

Comment: public boolean insertdatat(String caret,String amount,String amount_paid,String balance ){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues =new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(Col_CARET,caret);
        contentValues.put(Col_AMOUNT,amount);
        contentValues.put(Col_AMOUNT_PAID,amount_paid);
        contentValues.put(Col_BALANCE,balance);

        long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME2,null,contentValues);
        if(result== -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

Comment: @bipin try re-installing the application

Comment: @PankajNimgade i re installed nothing happend

Comment: can you pull the database from the DDMS to check if your application has this table ?